# Harry Potter fanfic where he stays in a sterilized environment in the hospital wing and Snape stays near him

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

This fan fiction starts with Harry and Snape becoming somewhat friendly with each other. Later they make each other magical bracelets by focussing on their magic. Harry never takes this bracelet of because of Severus' magic that it gives off. Harry got a plain black leather bracelet and Severus got a black and green one with maybe a panther (at least I think they were described that way).

Further along in the story something happened and caused Harry to be badly injured (I don't remember if it was a potions accident or something else with a lot of fire).
Harry got terrible burns and his throat and lungs are severely damaged, causing him to be in an enclosed area (maybe with only privacy screens) that has been completely sterilized and the air purified. His bracelet was taken of and Severus got it for safekeeping, since it got in the way of bandaging his arm.

(I also think that his eyes got damaged too and they were worried about the lasting damage. He got a few? drips of a potion given by Severus.)

Severus become almost glued to his bedside (he washed himself with unscented soap to keep the place sterile and the air purified). Harry panics the first time he wakes up when he couldn't find his bracelet, but it was only for a short period since Severus entered a few minutes later.

Draco also tries to become friends with Harry. Harry wakes up at one time and had asked Draco what he was doing at his bedside, to which he answered that he was watching him for the period that Severus was away. And then they were talking and then become friendly with each other. (I don't think there was any bashing, except for Ginny who is obsessed with Harry.)

Another time when Harry is making some slow progress Severus is called away and Pomfrey was busy in her office Ginny sneaks into the Hospital Wing. She is heavily perfumed, so when she goes to Harry's bed and hugs him, she nearly causes him to choke to death. Luckily she was forcibly dragged away from him (I don't remember by who — either Severus or Draco) and Severus tells her that she nearly undid all the progress Harry made while trying to get him stabilized again and magically purifying the air in Harry's lungs.

Ginny is then (being closely watched first maybe?) pinned to a bed and sedated, and is later sent to St. Mungo for a mindhealer.

This is all I can remember from the story, which takes place somewhere in his later 5+ years. I'm not sure if there is a pairing going on and I believe that Ron and Hermione both came to visit him a few times, and maybe brought some homework too? They did see Malfoy, but they also became more friendly toward each other. I think I saw this fic on archiveofourown (or on Fanfiction).

Comment: That’s a big wall of text. Maybe you could use a bullet list to highlight some key points? Or add some paragraphs in to make it a bit easier to read.

Comment: When did you read this?

Comment: The last time I read this story was more than two years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many days googling I have finally found the fic again.
Victory is mine :D

It was called '[Coping with Hope](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4447259/1/Coping-with-Hope)' by Laurenke1

From [Chapter 9](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4447259/9/Coping-with-Hope):

> "This
>   is it." Snape held out a dark leather
>   bracelet with a metal charm woven into it that bore a striking
>   resemblance to a striking snake but Harry wasn't sure when suddenly
>   the charm transformed into a flowing S. Harry glanced up, did Snape
>   really intend for him to have that bracelet? Harry had only ever worn
>   his watch and well, this kind of seemed like a bit girly.

....

> Harry
>   coughed to try and clear the smoke from his lungs and flushed
>   immediately. There, on Snape's hand was the same dark leather band
>   only this time with the H replaced with a panther which showed the
>   enormous fangs and had a paw extracted with the dangerous
>   claws but that wasn't the worst of it, no Harry actually felt quite
>   proud of the animal but it was the dark green bands suddenly woven
>   all around in the dark leather.